# MySQL dump on a new server is more quick than server running the same exact database

Tags: mysql

I have two servers with the exact database. One have the database since the begin, the other have the dump of the same database (tables/data). Running the same query on both server one respond 50+% more quickly (the one that was created with the dump) than the other.

Both are running MySQL 5.6 and DB engine is InnoDB and checking both configurations, the same. The size of the database is 146 tables with 1.6 GB of data. I think that one of the issues could be about the number of index that some tables have.

I've notice a stranger thing yesterday, that after running:

```
mysqlcheck -u root -p <db> --auto-repair --optimize
```

The server with the dump database had higher query time than before (similar to the first server), but today after several servers testing I can't reproduce it.

It makes any sense ?

EDIT: An example of a query

```
select  count(*) as aggregate
    from  `humans`
    left join  `reports`  ON `humans`.`id` = `reports`.`human`
      and  `reports`.`id` = 
    (
        SELECT  max(id)
            from  reports r
            where  r.human = reports.human
              and  r.trash = 0
              and  ((r.account = 13565
                              and  (r.user IN (0,13543,14638)
                                      or  r.group_id IN(3331)))
                      or  (
                            (
                                SELECT  count(*)
                                    from  report_access
                                    where  report_access.report_id = r.id
                                      and  report_access.status = 1
                                      and  (report_access.account_id = 13565
                                              and  (report_access.group_id in (3331)
                                                      or  report_access.user_id in (0,13543,14638)))) >= 1)
                   )
            group by  reports.human
    )
    where  `humans`.`trash` = '0'
      and  ((`humans`.`account` = '13565'
                      or  ((`humans`.`account` = '13558')
                              and  `humans`.`public` = '1'
                              and  `humans`.`status` != '0'
                          )
                      and  (`humans`.`status` != '0'
                              or  (`humans`.`status` = '0'
                                      and  (`humans`.`group_id` in ('3331')
                                              or  `humans`.`user` in ('0', '13543', '14638'))))
                          )
              or  (
                    (
                        SELECT  count(*)
                            from  `reports`
                            where  `reports`.`human` = `humans`.`id`
                              and  `reports`.`trash` = '0'
                              and  (((`reports`.`group_id` in ('3331')
                                                      or  `reports`.`user` in ('0', '13543', '14638')
                          )
                                              and  `reports`.`account` = '13565'
                          )
                                      or  
                                    (
                                        SELECT  count(*)
                                            from  `report_access`
                                            where  `report_access`.`report_id` = `reports`.`id`
                                              and  ((`report_access`.`group_id` in ('3331')
                                                              or  `report_access`.`user_id` in ('0', '13543', '14638'))
                                                      and  `report_access`.`account_id` = '13565'
                          )
                                              and  `report_type` in ('observation', 'profile')
                                              and  `status` = '1') >= 1)) >= 1)
           )
      and  
    (
        SELECT  count(*)
            from  `human_evaluations`
            where  `human_evaluations`.`human` = `humans`.`id`
              and  `human_evaluations`.`user` = '13543'
              and  `human_evaluations`.`value` = 'hot'
              and  `human_evaluations`.`account` = '13565'
              and  `human_evaluations`.`user` in ('0', '13543', '14638')
    ) >= 1
    order by  CASE WHEN reports.updated_at THEN 2 WHEN humans.account = 13565 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END desc,
        CASE WHEN reports.updated_at THEN reports.updated_at ELSE humans.updated_at END desc
```

This query is generated by Eloquent (Laravel) and I'm trying to optimize the PHP code that generate that query. The first thing is try to remove some costly sub query and use JOINS.

Comment: Compare `SHOW VARIABLES;` to look for differences.  Run each timing test twice -- to avoid caching differences.  Show us the query.

Comment: I've added the query, but I don't know if is any help. I'm trying to optimize some queries that abuse of sub query and try to do the same with JOINs.

Comment: What kind of ambient workload are you looking at? If the original server has other workload occuring and the new server does not, that can obviously effect performance. Similarly, how does the underlying hardware compare?

Comment: @JoshBonello, the server is a Azure A3 (4 core, 7GB Ram, 30GB Disk). The other ones I compare was my personal computer (MacBook 2014) and a Digital Ocean server (2 core / 1GB RAM / 30GB SSD). I've suggest to improve the server to a D class in Azure, but not sure how much help will do. I don't thing that the issue.

Comment: It's not a whole answer, but I'd expect very different performance on the two servers given the same workload. Server A has more memory/CPU to throw at it, but Server B has significantly better storage. Both contribute to query performance in different ways.

Answer (score 0):

*Possibly* the "statistics" on the tables are different.  (I assume the indexes are the same?)  `ANALYZE TABLE` would recompute the stats quickly; this *might* bring them in line with each other.  `OPTIMIZE` (which you did do) includes `ANALYZE`, so I guess this suggestion may not be useful.

Some sluggish parts:

`OR` is difficult to optimize.

`IN ( SELECT ... )` is terribly slow in some cases; ok in others.

This sounds like a mistake:

```
          and  `human_evaluations`.`user` = '13543'
          and  `human_evaluations`.`user` in ('0', '13543', '14638')
```

Do any of the tables have 'composite' indexes?  (That is, indexes with multiple columns.)

`EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM ... )` is faster than `( SELECT COUNT(*) FROM ... ) >= 1 )`

Comment: Thanks for you answers Rick. I will take a better look to the way that PHP code and Eloquent creates the query. Yes, some tables have composite indexes, mainly for account / trash columns and user_id / group_id columns.